# How do we call the standard coin of a certain mainnet?

Tags: ether, gas, mainnet

In ethereum, we use ether to pay gas.
And ether is the main coin of ethereum mainnet.

In BSC, BNB is used to pay gas.
And BNB is the main coin in BSC, something like the main coin of that chain.

I know that people call it as 'coin' for the standard coin of the chain and 'token' for
tokens made by people using contracts.

What I want to know is how should I call the 'coin' (standard token of the chain) in other terms.

Maybe something like 'main coin' or 'standard token'?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no set-in-stone rule for how to refer to ETH as a distinctive kind of coin as compared to ERC-20 tokens. The variants I heard most often are:

- Native cryptocurrency (as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum))
- Native asset
- Underlying asset
- Base coin
- Base cryptocurrency